# Typescript extends Express Request body

Tags: typescript, express

I have the following:

```
const fff = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response): Promise<void> => {...}
```

How can I declare that `req.body.xxx` is exist? So when I type `req.body.xxx` it would know that it exists on the `req.body` object?

Comment: @ThomasSablik It extends `Request` object. I want to extend `req.body`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your `Request` type, that type extends `express.Request` and you can set the request body type:

```
interface ILoginBody {
  username: string;
  password: number;
}

interface ILoginRequest extends Request {
  body: ILoginBody;
}

// use ILoginRequest instead of express.Request
const fff = async (req: ILoginRequest, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const { username, password } = req.body; // body now is an ILoginBody
}
```

Comment: will the server throw an error if req.body doesn't match ILoginBody?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for this based on the [TypeScript definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L112-L118)

```
interface Request<
        P = core.ParamsDictionary,
        ResBody = any,
        ReqBody = any,
        ReqQuery = core.Query,
        Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
    > extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals> {}
```

would be the following snippet taken from above where we specify the Request types inside the brackets.

```
interface ILoginBody {
  username: string;
  password: number;
}

const fff = async (req: Request<any, Response, ILoginBody>, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
}
```